# Change Xorg Config Based on Graphics Configuration

Tags: configuration, nvidia, display, xorg

Basically, we have a single OS that gets NFSRoot mounted everywhere, but the hardware being used can vary. We have a few different dual screen setups, some go through DVI KVMs and some go through DP KVMs. The DVI KVMs show up as different DP-#s that the DP ones, which, based on what I've read, using a single Xorg config not possible.

So I ended up down a rabbit hole of trying to figure out how to determine what is connected to the NVIDIA card where before X is started, so I can configure the Xorg layout correctly.

I've tried checking down `/sys/class/drm/card*/status` but only `card0` appears with no status file.

I've tried polling edid information, but the only way to do that appears to be with the `nvidia-settings` command, which only runs after X is running.

Its very much a chicken and egg situation where X needs to be running to see the DP-* connections, but I can't configure the DP-* connections to get X running.

Is there a way to either:

- Get Xorg to load multiple configs and be able to discern them on startup (i.e if DP-6 and DP-4 exist, use config1, if DP-5 and DP-7 exist, use config2... etc)
- Find out what is connected to the NVIDIA card where before X starts
- Some other solution I am blind to